# Integrating Jupyter Notebook Workspace on a Website and Granting User Code Spaces

Tags: flask, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, jupyterhub, flask-appbuilder

I would like to integrate a Jupyter Notebook workspace into my website, allowing my users to have their own code spaces and collaborate. How can I achieve this and grant permission for users to have their individual code spaces? Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on the following aspects:

```
Setting up the Jupyter Notebook workspace integration on my website: How can I embed or integrate a Jupyter Notebook workspace into my website? Are there any libraries or frameworks that can assist with this process?

Creating user accounts and managing permissions: What steps should I follow to enable users to register accounts on my website? How can I associate these accounts with their respective Jupyter Notebook code spaces? How do I manage permissions to ensure users only have access to their own code spaces?

Providing code execution capabilities: Once a user has their own code space, how can I allow them to execute their code within the Jupyter Notebook environment on my website? Are there any considerations regarding security and resource allocation that I need to take into account?
```

I appreciate any advice, tutorials, or code examples that can help me accomplish this integration.
Thank you!